# How can I get Ubuntu 12.04 to boot on a Gigabyte 990Fx MB (efi problem?)

Tags: boot-failure, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a home made system with a gigabyte 990Fxa MB.
I can make it through the install process.
It does not boot.
Windows 7 does boot on the same machine.
Suse 11.4 boots on the same machine.
Suse 12.4 does not boot.
I think there may be an issue with the EFI / GPT system.
I know very little about these systems. I really expected the machine to boot.
What can I do to get the system to boot?
Please direct me to a path to trouble shoot this problem.

thanks

Jeffrey

Comment: does the system boot while using a live CD?

Comment: If Rod's advice helped, please click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some troubleshooting of the boot process, beginning with two related questions:

- Is the computer's firmware attempting to start the boot process in BIOS mode or in EFI mode? (Either is possible on most modern EFI-enabled machines.)
- Did the problem OS(es) install BIOS-mode or EFI-mode boot loaders?

Basically, the boot loader installed by the OS must match the boot mode used by the motherboard. If they don't match, the system won't boot. Unfortunately, the EFI specification includes no standardized rules for determining the boot mode used by the computer, so manufacturers have been free to make up their own rules. These manufacturer-specific rules vary from one product to another and are seldom well-documented, so you may end up having to run experiments to figure out how to coax your board into booting in one mode or the other.

Generally speaking, if the computer boots Windows 7, the easiest course of action is to install Linux in a way that's compatible -- that is, in EFI mode if Windows is booting in EFI mode, and in BIOS mode if Windows already boots in BIOS mode. You can determine your Windows boot mode in various ways, such as by looking at the partition table -- if Windows is booting from an MBR disk, it's booting in BIOS mode, and if it's booting from a GPT disk, it's booting in EFI mode. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for more details.

Fortunately, switching the Linux boot mode is usually just a matter of uninstalling the non-functional boot loader installing a suitable boot loader in its place. For Ubuntu, grub-pc is the usual BIOS-mode boot loader and grub-efi is the usual EFI-mode boot loader; but in my experience, GRUB's EFI version is pretty flaky, so I personally prefer to use others. Switching out the Linux boot loader may require using an emergency boot disk. See [my Web page on the topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for a more thorough coverage of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess is that your new mothedoard BIOS support's UEFI.
Whit EFI / UEFI you have booting point at motherboard memory and
you get that easyly lost :

-After doing FRESH install you must also
UPDATE starting location to motherboard memory ,you might forget to
do that or installation script dose not note that!

-updateing BIOS will clear out EFI startup info as well.

-editing EFI BIOS SETTINGS can cause same !!!

At Ubuntu 12.4 precise simply BOOT computer WHIT UEFI whit your 
LIVE-CD, RESCUE DISK/STICK/USB and go repair mode.

You must get your self loged in / chrooted to your hard disk
and then reinstall EFI booting information to system memory 
as well update HARDDISK  information as well.

You need startup code  (at my system /sda) at starup hardisk loacated at /boot/efi
and whit my configuration mounting goes like this:

```
mount /dev/sda /boot/efi
```

So you got mounted booting part needed by grub-efi program to system
for reinstallation.

Just then to update motherboard UEFI memory settings as well
harddisk whit grub-efi  run:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

or

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
update-grub
```

This should do all needed work (memory, harddisk) things and then just reboot!!!

MORE: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/UEFI_Firmware  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Answer (score 0):

When you make your bootable linux flash drive, make it on a windows computer. Then the gigabyte will boot from it and install just fine.